# Issues Installing Windows Mobile 6.0 and 6.5

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

Since the news that the WinMo app store is accepting applications, i've tried downloading and installing the 6.5 dev kit.

First i install 6.0, then 6.5.  In Visual Studio 2008, when i try to create a new Smart Device Project, there are no 6.5 devices in the target platform dropdown.

Is this correct?  Is my install just wonky, or is 6.5 really just 6.0 apps with a bunch of added libraries?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, from the .net cf side of things, there is nothing new in the api.  By the look of things, the big change with 6.5 is prettier UI.

http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2009/03/18/windows-mobile-6-5-what-s-in-for-developers.aspx